# Problem after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login

I've recently updated my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. When it's restarted, I typed my password but nothing happened after that. It's still on the login screen.
On the login screen, it says ubuntu 13.10 but when I run the terminal (Ctrl + Alt+F1) it says 14.04. What can be the cause for this and how can I fix this?

Comment: It might be due to the wrong updation in nvidia driver so sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

Comment: Can you try to be very precise please because it is important: What exactly happens after you typed your password and pressed enter? Does the login screen change and return to a new login screen again or does it stay exactly the same?

Comment: @halirutan the login screen doesn't change, even though the password's confirmed.